# Common exploits of port 843

Tags: security, penetration-testing

Found the port 843 open on an ip of a site with bug bounty. Its an adobe cross domain policy server. I am new to bug bounty so am stuck on this part can somebody help me proceed. I need to find a vulnerability and exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

Flash socket cross-domain exploit:

Bypasses the same-origin-policy using Flash sockets and an overly permissive socket policy (crossdomain.xml on port 843 by default).

To compile and deploy:

Download the Apache Flex SDK from [ http://flex.apache.org/]
Modify the targetName, data, and sendTo parameters in SocketCrossDomain.as
Compile using mxmlc from the Flex SDK:
     mxmlc SocketCrossDomain.as
Deploy SocketCrossDomain.swf and exploit.html to the same web directory